# How to only get "true" elements from json

Tags: php, if-statement

I only want to get the true elements, i can do that, but it also outputs a lot of blank spaces

This is what a news line look like

```
  "news": [
    {
      "title": "Titulo",
      "body": "Aqui fica o conteudo",
      "image": "Imagem",
      "live": true
    },
```

And i'm doing this to get the news

```
<?php foreach ( $json['news'] as $noticias ) : ?>

 <?php 

if($noticias['live'] == "true"):

echo $noticias['title'];

?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This outputs only the "true", but also outputs a lot of spaces like this

```
Titulo
Titulo
Titulo
```

Comment: Try an var_dump on your `$noticias['title']`

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you! Still didn't know that i did wrong but your code worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use trim() function to get rid of whitespaces.

Comment: `echo ['title']` is not the same as `echo ['live']  so there could be an differance.

Answer (score 0):

Your closing and opening of PHP tags adds whitespace. Use one PHP block,

```
<?php 
foreach ( $json['news'] as $noticias ) :
    if($noticias['live'] == "true"):
        echo $noticias['title'];
    endif;
endforeach;
```

This is noted in the manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php,

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. **This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag**, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.